# Is it possible to use Transformer model for binary classification of unbalanced panel data?

Tags: time-series, panel-data, binary-data, natural-language, transformers

So I have unbalanced panel data, i.e. multivariate time series with different lengths for each individual and a binary label at each time point. I was thinking to use some deep learning approach and NLP techniques can deal with sequences, is it possible to use Transformer model or binary classification somehow ? Did anyone try something like that before?

EDIT: I am asking for transformer, bcs I need some interpretability. LSTM can not do that...

Comment: Maybe a LSTM model? When you have different lengths (timesteps) you can pad the sequence to make all sequences have the same length, and then use a recurrent neural network.

Comment: Yes, I forgot I need some interpretability, I will add it to question.